# Stored procedure with table type parameter returns data but SqlDataAdapter will not fill

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes, sqldataadapter

I'm passing a data table to stored procedure (using a table type) to update multiple records at once. SQL profiler shows the stored procedure executing and the records are updated; however, I'm also returning a data set to a SqlDataAdapter. When I execute this in SSMS, I get the results. When I run this in code, rows are not being received.

Any ideas? I'm clueless on why the SqlDataAdapter isn't being filled. Oddly enough, I can get a tables count, but no rows for any tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SGT_UpdateSGT]
 @SGT_GuidelinesTbl As [dbo].[SGT_GuidelinesTbl] Readonly
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 update g set Disposition=sgt.Disposition, DispositionDate=GETDATE() from SGTGuidelineRequests g inner join @SGT_GuidelinesTbl sgt on g.pkid=sgt.pkid

 select u.ForeName, u.Email, g.* 
 from @SGT_GuidelinesTbl sgt
 inner join SGTGuidelineRequests g on g.pkid=sgt.pkid
 inner join Users u on u.NBID=g.SubmittedBy
END
GO
```

c# code. The session is being filled

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable queue = (DataTable)Session["SGTKeepDeleteQueue"];
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SQLConn.CWFMO()))
{
  sqlConnection.Open();
  SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SGT_UpdateSGT", sqlConnection);
  sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  SqlParameter guidelinesTblParam = new SqlParameter();
  guidelinesTblParam.ParameterName = "@SGT_GuidelinesTbl";
  guidelinesTblParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
  guidelinesTblParam.Value = queue;
  sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(guidelinesTblParam);

  SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
  sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

And this is what SQL Profiler receives. When I execute this, I get at least 1 row of data.

```
declare @p1 dbo.SGT_GuidelinesTbl
insert into @p1 values(1,N'Approved',N'8/23/2012 12:00:00 AM')

exec SGT_UpdateSGT @SGT_GuidelinesTbl=@p1
```

Comment: Might help to show your C# code (and preferably the smallest amount of code that demonstrates the problem), since you've already explained that the stored procedure works.

Comment: I can tomorrow but I know the code works. I've tested the sproc in SSMS and a c# function. I think it has something to do with joining on  a table type. It's like the query works in SSMS but fails in the data adapter.

Comment: You know the code works, yet here we are trying to blindly figure out why you're trying to solve a problem that sounds a lot like it doesn't work. We can't fix what we can't see. <shrug>

Comment: I added the c# portion that calls the sproc, thanks!

Comment: You should check out with SQL Profiler what command is being sent.

Comment: I have. I got the command that is sent, executed in SSMS and it returns data. I read that sometimes data sets that SQL may return some how don't work for a SqlDataAdapter but I have no idea why.

Comment: Why did this get marked down? It's not like I asked how to open Visual Studio. I've have looked and continue to look for an answer.

Comment: I tesed with SqlDataReader and it returns data but SqlDataAdapter does not. Odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the name of the SqlDataAdapter and it works. I'm not sure why, I didn't name it that anywhere else in the file. Cleaning the solution didn't solve this either. At least it works.