# How to retrieve rows using SqlDataAdapter with a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

I have looked at numerous questions about this such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067342/c-sharp-adapter-fill-dataset-not-working-with-stored-procedure-even-though-i-kno) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062413/stored-procedure-with-table-type-parameter-returns-data-but-sqldataadapter-will). These all have been able to give me the proper code, but I receive no results.

```
DataTable CI = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    //TODO: Check functionality of stored procedure 
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "spCreateCIR";

        SqlParameter categoryParameter = new SqlParameter("@cat", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = cat,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        };

        command.Parameters.Add(categoryParameter);
        connection.Open(); 

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        CIR = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(CIR);      
    }
}
```

So I went and tried another method using the SqlReader and it worked properly and brought back the data that I intended to receive as shown in the following code.

```
ObservableCollection<TYPE> CIR = new ObservableCollection<TYPE>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    //TODO: Check functionality of stored procedure 
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "spCreateCIR";

        SqlParameter categoryParameter = new SqlParameter("@cat", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = cat,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        };

        command.Parameters.Add(categoryParameter);

        connection.Open();
        IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteReader();
        while (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        SqlDataReader reader = command.EndExecuteReader(result);

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                TYPE CIL = new TYPE();
                CIL.Venue = reader.GetString(0); 
                CIR.Add(CIL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any thoughts or ideas to reason why I get a null return?

Comment: If you run your stored procedure manually does it return results?

Comment: Also in your first one you are using da.Fill(CatInv); What is CatInv? Shouldn't it be the CIR DataTable.

Comment: Yes I just caught it....  thanks. As for manual returns yes I get a full page of results when I run the stored procedure through SSMS.

Comment: Dunno then. It should work. Would it possibly be the parameter you are using just isn't returning any results?

Comment: Try putting your results into a dataset. If you are getting more than one result set (someone left a debug/trace query uncommented), then it will mess with loading your single DT.  Put a break-point and confirm how many table(s), rows, etc.